# Return an array from a lookup

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, worksheet-function

I have a table with column A containing vendors and column B containing product codes. One vendor has many product codes.

In another place I need an array of product codes for a specific vendor. The vendor-product table is dynamic and new items are continuously added.

An example: Vendor-product sheet has the above described structure and has several thousand rows. A working sheet has column A with a vendor name and I want to provide a pull down list of named vendor's products in column B. For this I need a way to provide the array for the data validity.

Can this be done?

Comment: Hmm - for several thousand rows, i would think about importing the data into an SQL db (LO Base?) and continue working there.

Comment: It won't grow to that degree. I think it will top at around 3-4000 rows. Too little to go into DB development. I also need the same technique for shorter lists with less than hundred rows and a dozen B items for each A entity. So in general I'm still looking for the theoretical answer regardless of how it fits 3000 rows :)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that the purpose of a filter?

Copy the vendor-product table in another sheet with an array formula, and filter in that new sheet by the vendor.

Note: to copy with Array formula. Suppose the original table is from A1 to B1000. But you expect several thousand rows, so lets assume it is until B1048576 (The max number is given in my machine).

In the new sheet select A1 to B104876 (click on A1, hold shift and move one cell right so you have selecte A1:B1, hold control and press down, which will select A1:B104876, then release the keys).

Then write the formula `=Sheet.A1:B104876` and press combined control, shift and enter in order to apply the Array formula. Now, Whatever appear en range `Sheet1.A1:B104876` will appear in range `Sheet2.A1:B104876`, and you can then filter there by whatever you want.

Warning, this technique will slowdown your machine, so instead of using arrays of 104876 rows, try to use a lower number.